# Using map function in swift to make MKPointAnnotations

Tags: swift, mapkit, map-function

I have an array of "place" objects with coordinates and names.

for example:

```
let places = [place(name: "Eiffel Tower", latitude: 48.8582, longitude: 2.2945), place(name: "Statue of Liberty", latitude: 40.6892, longitude: -74.0444), place(name: "Tower of London", latitude: 51.5081, longitude: -0.0761)]
```

From this array, I would like to create a new array of MKPointAnnotations using map.  I know it starts like this:

```
let placeAnnotations = places.map{ (place -> MKPointAnnotation // but that's about all I know for sure!}
```

... I don't know how to set MKPointAnnotation's .coordinate and .title properties without committing some syntax error.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track. This is the full code:

```
let places = [place(name: "Eiffel Tower", latitude: 48.8582, longitude: 2.2945), place(name: "Statue of Liberty", latitude: 40.6892, longitude: -74.0444), place(name: "Tower of London", latitude: 51.5081, longitude: -0.0761)]

let annotations = places.map { aPlace -> MKPointAnnotation in
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: aPlace.latitude, longitude: aPlace.longitude)
    return annotation
}

println(annotations)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for -- much appreciated.  Sorry I don't have the reputation to upvote the answer.

Comment: I'm glad this is of help to you :) Nevermind, I'm not here for the reps ;)